# Visual Studio 2013 Picturebox Mouseover/Click Issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe game for my Visual Basic course (yes, there are literally hundreds of valid code examples out there, but I want this to be my code) and I've hit a bit of a snag.
I have the program setup so that when you mouseover the picturebox, the users "X" is displayed, and it disappers on mouseleave. This functions beautifully, however when that box is clicked the image doesn't stay and I need it to. I have included one of each of the types of code, can you help me figure out what I'm missing?
Thank you!

```
'These subs display the users X upon mouseover
Private Sub TRCorner_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TRCorner.MouseMove
    TRCorner.Image = Image.FromFile("X.jpg")
End Sub

'These subs return the image to the border upon mouseleave
Private Sub TRCorner_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TRCorner.MouseLeave
    TRCorner.Image = Image.FromFile("Border.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub TRCorner_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TRCorner.Click

    'Choose X or O image upon click
    TRCorner.Image = Image.FromFile("X.jpg")

End Sub
```

Comment: Your MouseLeave event handler is borken.  It should *not* restore the Image property when the user selected an X or O.  Use a variable to keep track of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make the handler behave differently when you click on it. 
The handler in your case keeps doing what it does - setting your image on mouseleave-event.
For the application the click-event does not disable the mouseleave-event.

You could use a public boolean for each button you have to define the behaviour you want.
that value could changed by you on the click-event so you can disable the mouseleave-event (setting the button-image)

```
  If clicked = true Then
        TRCorner.Image = Image.FromFile("X.jpg")
    Else

    End If
```

Comment: Thanks! This set me on the right path. I ended up fixing the game with the following code:

Private Sub BRCorner_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BRCorner.MouseLeave

        If clicked = True Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            BRCorner.Image = Image.FromFile("Border.jpg")
        End If

    End Sub